# Calculating boundaries for a multiple integral from inequalities

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

I was trying to solve for the region enclosed by `y=Sqrt[x]`, `z=1+x+y`, `y=0`, and `x=1`, to evaluate a triple integral of 6xy.

So far I have tried to this code to only an error.

```
Integrate[(6*x*y)Boole[z=1+x+y && y==Sqrt[x] &&y==0 && x==1], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {z, -∞, ∞}]
```

Could someone please help me understand how to calculate a region in Mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is right?

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[ y <=  Sqrt[x] && z == 1 + x + y &&  y >= 0 && x <= 1, {x, y, z}]
% // Region
Integrate[6*x*y, {x, y, z} ∈ reg]
```

> `Sqrt[3]`

**Another way**

According to the definition of the integral along a surface.

The normal of the surface `z-(1+x+y)==0` is `Grad[z - (1 + x + y), {x, y, z}`

```
Integrate[
 6 x*y*Norm[Grad[z - (1 + x + y), {x, y, z}]], {x, y} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[y <= Sqrt[x] && y >= 0 && x <= 1, {x, y}]]
```

> `Sqrt[3]`

Comment: Here's the `Boole[]` version of the last snippet: `Integrate[6 x y Norm[Grad[z - (1 + x + y), {x, y, z}]] Boole[0 <= y <= Sqrt[x] && x <= 1], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]`